# Is there any way to load async images faster in swiftui?

Tags: swift, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

I'm making an app in SwiftUI where I'm using links from Firebase Storage to load images with `AsyncImage`.

The problem is that it takes about 1 second to load these images, which is a long time for a small image.

This is an example of how I'd load an image in my app:

```swift
var link = "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com:443/v0/b/tribum-7b19a.appspot.com/o/1EVKeHBGLoULDCYA5nrS34Zbqgp1?alt=media&token=04f4444a-75bd-4895-9c79-516718174223"

//...

AsyncImage(url: URL(string: link)) { image in
    image
        .resizable()
        .scaledToFill()
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
        .clipShape(Circle())
} placeholder: {
    Image(systemName: "person.crop.circle.fill")
        .resizable()
        .foregroundColor(.gray)
        .frame(width: 25, height: 25)
}
```

As you can see, the link itself leads to an image from my storage, but the image might be too large for what I need (I only need a circle with width and height set to 25)

Comment: If all you need is a tiny image, just save the small image into storage. It will be cheaper in the long run because they charge per download.

Comment: @loremipsum how do I store smaller images then?

Comment: You would have to reduce the size of the image, it all depends on the source and how you save it to the database, there are several approaches.

Comment: If you need lots of images, there are also services ([uploadcare](https://uploadcare.com) is one but there are others) that offer an image CDN and can scale images for you based on url parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The problem is that it takes about 1 second to load these images, which is a long time for a small image.

The image example you have added in your question, is not as small as you say. It's a 3000*2000 pixels image having almost 700KB. So downloading such an image in 1 second sounds reasonable to me. What you have to do in such cases, is to reduce the size of the image. You can do that when you upload the image to Storage using your own mechanism, or you can use a Firebase Extension such as [Resize Images](https://extensions.dev/extensions/firebase/storage-resize-images) which:

> Resizes images uploaded to Cloud Storage to a specified size, and optionally keeps or deletes the original image.